# How to turn off File Browser prompt?

Tags: user-interface

Is there a way to turn off this feature?

[image]

It is very slow and totally unnecessary for me. I have tried to look for a setting in preferences but I couldn't find the right box to untick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set the (documented) cell option

```
CodeAssistOptions -> {"FileCompleteEnable" -> False}
```

then the File Browser popup won't appear when editing the cell.  Alternatively, you can set the option for an entire notebook:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
 CodeAssistOptions -> {"FileCompleteEnable" -> False}]
```

Finally, you could change the style of `"Input"` cells by using a custom stylesheet or editing a private stylesheet for the notebook.